# Returning functions in scheme

Tags: scheme, higher-order-functions, the-little-schemer

I have been playing about with *The Little Schemer*, and am trying ideas as i work through (not all of which are working out).  Just now, i am in Chapter 6 (where they introduce helper functions) and i *feel* that a step is within reach -- i just don't know how to make that step.

The code from the book is as follows:

```
(define (^ b e) (expt b e))

(define (x a b) (* a b))

(define value-i
  (lambda (nexp)
    (cond
      ((atom? nexp) nexp)
      ((eq? (car (cdr nexp)) '+) (+ (car nexp) (value-i (caddr nexp))))
      ((eq? (car (cdr nexp)) 'x) (x (car nexp) (value-i (caddr nexp))))
      (else
        (^ (car nexp) (value-i (caddr nexp))))
      )))
```

The following helpers are defined:

```
(define (operator-i aexp) (car (cdr aexp)))
(define (firstSubExp-i aexp) (car aexp))
(define (secondSubExp aexp) (caddr aexp))
```

And this simplification is made:

```
(define value-i2
  (lambda (nexp)
    (cond
      ((atom? nexp) nexp)
      ((eq? (operator-i nexp) '+) (+ (firstSubExp-i nexp) 
                                     (value-i2 (secondSubExp nexp))))
      ((eq? (operator-i nexp) 'x) (x (firstSubExp-i nexp) 
                                     (value-i2 (secondSubExp nexp))))
      (else
        (eq? (operator-i nexp) '^) (^ (firstSubExp-i nexp) 
                                      (value-i2 (secondSubExp nexp))))
      )))
```

The simplification i *think* i can see is that as we assume all `nexp` are valid, we don't need to repeat the `((eq? (operator-i nexp) ...` boilerplate.

Something like the following should work:

```
(define value-i3
  (lambda (nexp)
    (cond
      ((atom? nexp) nexp)
      (else
        ((operator-i nexp) 
         (firstSubExp-i nexp) 
         (value-i3 (secondSubExp nexp))))
      )))
```

... except that it does not. It errors out with `Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure ...` (one of +, x and ^).

I can see that the problem is that it does not recognise that i am trying to call a function with `(operator-i nexp)`.

How do i make clear to the interpreter that i wish to apply the function i am returning from `(operator-i nexp)`?

Any other tips are also welcome (i am using petite chez scheme).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `value-i3` doesn't work because `(operator-i nexp)` returns a symbol, not a procedure object. Notice the difference between `'+` and `+`?

There's not really an easy way to get around that (if we rule out `eval`, which is gross and disrecommended), other than using an alist to link the symbol with the procedure (or using `case` or `cond` as mentioned in Sylwester's answer):

```
(define symbol->procedure
  (let ((opmap `((+ ,+)
                 (x ,x)
                 (^ ,^))))
    (lambda (x)
      (cond ((assq x opmap) => cadr)
            (else #f)))))
```

Then use `symbol->procedure` the same way as Sylwester's answer.

If you find quasiquotes too difficult to read, you can use `list` and `cons` directly;

```
(define symbol->procedure
  (let ((opmap (list (cons '+ +)
                     (cons 'x x)
                     (cons '^ ^))))
    (lambda (x)
      (cond ((assq x opmap) => cdr)
            (else #f)))))
```

---

The OP asked for more information about `assq` and the like, so I thought I'd update the post directly. Basically, `(assoc key alist)` returns the first item in `alist` whose `car` is `equal?` to `key`, or `#f` otherwise; `assq` and `assv` are similar to `assoc` but use `eq?` and `eqv?` as the comparison operator. So, here's a sample implementation (with R7RS/SRFI-1 semantics):

```
(define (find pred lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((pred (car lst)) (car lst))
        (else (find pred (cdr lst)))))

(define assoc
  (case-lambda
    ((key alist equal?)
     (find (lambda (x)
             (equal? key (car x)))
           alist))
    ((key alist)
     (assoc key alist equal?))))

(define (assq key alist)
  (assoc key alist eq?))

(define (assv key alist)
  (assoc key alist eqv?))
```

Comment: how disappointing. I had thought this was what all that fuss about first class functions was all about ...

Comment: Lots of love for the alist solution ;-)

Comment: +1 / accepted. however, one thing: can you please explain exactly what the `assq x opmap` bit does? I think it tests if x is defined in opmap, but i'm a little unclear how it works.

Comment: @ricardo I've updated the post to answer your question, but yes, it basically does what you described. The assoc functions returns the association itself (e.g., `\`(+ ,+)` in the first code snippet, `(cons '+ +)` in the second), so we use `cadr` or `cdr` respectively (in combination with `cond`'s special `=>` syntax) to extract just the procedure value.

Comment: (Note: `(cadr \`(+ ,+))` = `(cdr (cons '+ +))` = `+`.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with you assumnption is that `operator-i` returns a symbol.
When you do `(+ 1 2)` the `+` gets evaluated to a procedure and that makes the form callable. However in the operator position in your code the result is the symbol `'+`. It then tries to apply a symbol instead of a procedure. Here is the minimal example of the two:

```
('+ 1 2) ; won't work
(+ 1 2)  ; works
```

You can make a lookup between them of course:

```
(define (symbol->procedure sym)
  (case sym
    ((+) +)
    ((x) x)
    ((^) ^)
    (else #f)))

((symbol->procedure '+) 2 3) ; ==> 5
```

Comment: The only change I would suggest to this answer would be to use `cond` rather than `case`. The problem with `case` here is that its auto-quoting form obscures the translation from symbols to functions. a `cond` clause would instead read: `[(eq? sym '+) +]` .

Comment: @JohnClements ...no love for the alist solution? It's just as O(n) as the `cond`/`case` solution, doesn't confuse the symbol-to-procedure translation, and (in my opinion) more succinct. ;-)

Comment: @JohnClements True that it's not obvious for those who are not familiar with `case` but it's been around since R2RS and all syntax, like `cond` with it's extra parenthesis, look strange if you haven't used it before. My opinion is that `case` was a good fit here.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yep, that one looks fine too... though the lookup function uses way too much insider-scheme for my taste. I would define the a-list outside the function, and the special `=>` syntax for cond is another layer of trickiness.

Comment: @JohnClements Thanks for introducing the term "insider-Scheme"; I've [put it to good use](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/747/3). :-D But yeah, I don't really know a nice way to use `assoc` and the like without using `cond`'s `=>`. It's either that or I'd have to throw in a `let` plus `and`.

Comment: @JohnClements - thanks very much for the `cond` example, it just helped me in chapter 8 of _TLS_. A funny thing happened, when i used `x` instead of `sym` it seems to have returned the variable `x` rather than the function `x` (which points to *) -- is this is the result of functions and variables sharing the same namespace? or is there more to the scoping rules?

Comment: @ricardo - it's hard to tell without seeing your code. Yes, there is only one namespace for variables.